# How to Group and Sort Objects in ObjectListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, grouping, objectlistview

I am trying to group my list of objects in an `ObjectListView`.

The `ObjectListView` should group the objects based on the first column but then have that same column sorted based on a custom sort.

How do I do that? I have read through the documentation for `ObjectListView`:
http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/gettingStarted.html#gettingstarted

So far, I have implemented my custom sort but I am not sure how to trigger the grouping? Remember that I am trying to group on the first column but then apply a custom sort.

My custom sort relis on the `BeforeSorting` event:

```
// after initializing components
olv.BeforeSorting += olv_BeforeSorting;
```

Then...

```
private void olv_BeforeSorting(object sender,BrightIdeasSoftware.BeforeSortingEventArgs e)
{
        olvDataSource.Sort((x, y) => x.Group.ID.CompareTo(y.Group.ID));
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

The `ObjectListView` displays my ordered object list but it is not grouped together. Each object displays on its own row without a group heading.

How do I group my objects after sorting them?

Comment: "group" by what? It appears to be sorting by ID, to further sort into "groups" (what ever they may be) then, you would do it there when sorting by ID.

Comment: Ah, okay. So instead of sorting how can I group them, then sort the groups using custom sort?

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is. I recommend creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) WITH DATA. I also recommend taking a closer look at the `ObjectListView` documentation, it appears the sorting as you describe is done automatically when the column header is clicked.

Comment: Therefore, it appears that your code (wiring up the `BeforeSort` event and sorting by ID) would be unnecessary. The `ObjectListView` should do this automatically when the ID column header is clicked. `ShowGroups` appears to simply “group” the data by the first character for the column header clicked. Without knowing what you are trying to achieve, may make it difficult getting an answer.

Comment: @JohnG Thanks for the follow up. I can see how my question is not very descriptive. I will add additional details and try to clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sharing this for anyone that might come across here looking for a way to apply a custom sort on groups within an `ObjectListView`.

There might be better ways to do this, but this way worked for me.

```
colFirst.GroupFormatter = (BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVGroup group, BrightIdeasSoftware.GroupingParameters parms) =>
{
    ObjectA a = (OjectA)group.Key;

    /* Add any processing code that you need */

    group.Task = " . . . ";
    group.Header = "Special Name: " + a.Name;
    group.Subtitle = $("Object A: {a.Index}, Total Water Consumption: {a.WaterConsumption}");

    // This is what is going to be used as a comparable in the GroupComparer below
    group.Id = a.ID;

    // This will create the iComparer that is needed to create the custom sorting of the groups
    parms.GroupComparer = Comparer<BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVGroup>.Create((x, y) => (x.GroupId.CompareTo(y.GroupId)));
};
```

The `OLVColumn.GroupFormatter` is lightly explained here:
http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-put-an-image-next-to-a-group-heading

Answer (score 4):

You can force the grouping column as follows:

```cs
olv.ShowGroups = true;
olv.AlwaysGroupByColumn = olvColumn1;
```

If you want to show one value in the column and group by a different one you can use `GroupByKeyGetter`

```
olvColumn1.GroupKeyGetter = GroupKeyGetter;
```

Delegate would be something like:

```
private object GroupKeyGetter(object rowObject)
{
    var o = rowObject as MyClass;

    if(o == null)
        return "unknown";

    return o.ID;
}
```

Some stuff doesn't take affect till you call

```
olv.RebuildColumns();
```

### Always Sort By (Arbitrary Function)

If you want to force sorting on some custom logic you can use `ListViewItemSorter` in the `BeforeSorting` event.  This is similar to registering a `CustomSorter` (but that doesn't seem to work when `ShowGroups` is true).

```
olv.BeforeSorting += olv_BeforeSorting;
```

Then

```
private void olv_BeforeSorting(object sender, BrightIdeasSoftware.BeforeSortingEventArgs e)
{
    //example sort based on the last letter of the object name
    var s = new OLVColumn();
    s.AspectGetter = (o) => ((MyClass)o).Name.Reverse().First(); 

    this.olv.ListViewItemSorter = new ColumnComparer(
                s, SortOrder.Descending, e.ColumnToSort, e.SortOrder);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I implemented your code, but as soon as I add my sort event (probably because of the `e.Handled = true;` nothing is grouped, but as soon as I comment out that line, I get my groups.
**The problem now** is that my groups are not sorted in the order that I want them to be. Any ideas on what I can do to get the groupings (custom) sorted the way I need them?

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `olvDataSource.Sort...` bit but leave in `e.Handled = true` ? Maybe that is having side effects? What Type is `olvDataSource`? normally you wouldnt sort the collection you would sort the olv control itself.

Comment: Ive updated answer with how I would enforce custom sorting while still keeping groups.  See if that works for you as an alternative to sorting your olvDataSource which doesn't feel right.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I implement your suggestions but the sorting seams to overwrite the grouping. I get all my rows sorted but no grouping. Everything is displayed as individual rows without group headings.
There is a `GroupFormatter` that is being applied to the grouping column, would that interfere with the process?
To be honest with you this is pre-existing code that I am trying to modify. So this has been a learning experience for me.

Comment: I ended up modifying the `GroupFormatter` on the group column. The `GroupFormatter` takes a delegate, so I modified the `BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVGroup` in it to allow for the sorting. I will add my solution as one of the answers. Please let me know what you think or share any suggestions that you might have. Thanks again.

Comment: Thats wierd behaviour, I've added a `GroupFormatter` and I cant get that behaviour to replicate (the formatter works fine and sorting doesnt break anything).  It almost makes me think that the disapearing groups is a side effect of something else like an Exception being thrown while building groups after sorting.  I like your solution of the comparer into the group formatter that feels right (like working with the API rather than against it).

Comment: Thanks for the dialogue around this issue. It really helped me understand what is going on, and to implement a solution that works "with the API rather than against it." You were very helpful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This works and is basically what is described in the cookbook here http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html?highlight=sort#how-can-i-change-the-ordering-of-groups-or-rows-within-a-group

First subscribe to the olv BeforeCreatingGroups event.

Then create a custom sort comparator in the event handler.  In this case for a group matching "Turtles" it will push to the end of the sort, but you can obviously have however much convoluted logic you want in there.

```
private void Olv_BeforeCreatingGroups(object sender, CreateGroupsEventArgs e)
{
    e.Parameters.GroupComparer = Comparer<BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVGroup>.Create(
        (x, y) => (
            x.Header == "Turtles" ? 1
                : x.GroupId.CompareTo(y.GroupId)
        )
    );
}
```

This is what I used initially since it's what was in the cookbook.  But I ended up switching to something more like Marwan's answer because that one creates a space to reconfigure the group headers themselves.